# Unable to interrupt program (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I am running a program in the terminal using `ipython` which has `plot.show()` command and after closing the plot figure, I don't get the command line in the terminal. Nothing happens on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> takes me out of the `ipython` environment killing the program. This never happened in Ubuntu 14.04 but I am facing this problem in Ubuntu 16.04. I am using the below program as an example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-1.,1.,129)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

Running the above program in `ipython` and closing the plot figure, I don't get the command line and the pointer just keeps on blinking. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> kills the program and I lose all the variables. Even for making some changes in the figure, I have to re-run the code.

Any help for this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose for most people this just runs fine as expected. So this is probably caused by something not meantionned in the question. Try to make this as reproducible for others as possible by clearly stating all relevant versions, how you installed everything, how you run it etc.

Comment: I am using `Python 2.7` and `matplotlib 2.1.2`. I a logging into ipython using the terminal and then running the script.

Comment: You could try using `plt.gcf().show()` instead of `plt.show()` when working inside ipython.  Not sure if it solves your problem though.

Comment: Thanks `plt.gcf().show()` works

Comment: Did you check your `stty` settings?